# Why are labels contained within listview stackpanels handled differently by my event handler then regular labels

Tags: c#, wpf

Was unsure how to word the question but it's as follows.

I have this event handler:

```
 private void labelenterhandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        try
        {
            oldbrush = ((Label)sender).Foreground;

            ((Label)sender).Foreground = Brushes.White;
            ((Label)sender).Effect = new System.Windows.Media.Effects.DropShadowEffect
            {
                Color = new Color { A = 255, R = 0, G = 0, B = 255 },
                Direction = 320,
                ShadowDepth = 0,
                Opacity = 1
            };
        }
        catch
        {

        }

    }
```

Now, For every label being used as a button I've taken the labelname and gone

```
labelname.MouseEnter += new MouseEventHandler(labelenterhandler);
```

Which works as shown here(The mouse is over shipping method) :

[image]

After loading a list of classnamehere from the database it clears the listview and I create a stack panel for each item in the list (With labels in it, that have the same exact event handler for MouseEnter)

But when I put my mouse over items on the grid, the border of the label control gets the dropshadoweffect instead of the text like this :

[image]

Is there any way of making the actual text get the dropshadoweffect within the listview?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the labels within the listview had a background color, and the shadow effect only goes on the actual text if the background is transparent.